# How to write unhandled exceptions into audit logs in abp

Tags: .net-core, abp

Unhandled exceptions can only be logged in detail into audit logs when
`SendExceptionsDetailsToClients` set true. But exception should not be send to clients in production.

I don't konw why audit logging module can not get the exception detail,is it triggered by action filter? It runs after exception filer?
thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.As it is said in the question,`SendExceptionsDetailsToClients` is the key. I checked the source code and found  that audit log also flows this setting.
Just custom a converter to repalce the `AuditLogInfoToAuditLogConverter`, and modify these 2 lines ,both set true.

```cs
//AuditLogInfoToAuditLogConverter.cs
var remoteServiceErrorInfos = auditLogInfo.Exceptions?.Select(exception => ExceptionToErrorInfoConverter.Convert(exception, options =>
               {
                   options.SendExceptionsDetailsToClients = true;//ExceptionHandlingOptions.SendExceptionsDetailsToClients;
                   options.SendStackTraceToClients = true;//ExceptionHandlingOptions.SendStackTraceToClients;
               }))?? new List<RemoteServiceErrorInfo>();
```